# Supported orientation madness

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I know this is the most commonly asked question and trust me I have tried every kind of combination to make this happen and went through most posts here on stack overflow.

I have a UINavigationController called v1ViewController and what I am trying to do is when it is shown to the user I just want it to either show in portrait or portrait-up-side-down modes, no landscape even if the user rotates the device in landscape it shouldn't do anything.

NOTE: I did highlight all options in Xcode for supported interface orientations as in one of my other view controller I need to show user something in both landscape and portrait modes but for this UINav Conrtoller I want it to just remain in portrait modes.

The code I have for iOS 5.0 work just fine without a problem.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

the headache I have is with iOS 6. No matter what I try and do it still lets the user rotate the bloody thing in landscape (see code and screenshots)

```
// *********************
// iPhone 5 orientation support
// *********************
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];


    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}


-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure you override the base UINavigationController and assign a custom class to it(not just the viewController that is the subview for the UINavController..ie the view contained below the navigationBar). Inside the UINavigationController, return NO on shouldAutoRotate.

Comment: I did that. As you can see above I am using my custom class @interface v1ViewController : UIViewController

Comment: Yeah exactly. v1ViewController is the viewController contained inside of the navController..NOT the actual navigationController..You need to assign a class to the UINavigationController and override that.. ie it would be like: @interface yourNavController:UINavigationController